# MSVC friend function declaration bug

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<size_t value> class dummy { };

class my_class
{
    int m_member;

    // Overload 1
    template<size_t value>
    friend void friend_func(dummy<value>*);

    // Overload 2
    template<size_t value>
    friend void friend_func(int(*)[value]);
};

// Overload 1
template<size_t value>
void friend_func(dummy<value>*)
{
    my_class instance;
    instance.m_member = value;
}

// Overload 2
template<size_t value>
void friend_func(int(*)[value])
{
    my_class instance;
    instance.m_member = value;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    dummy<5> d;
    friend_func(&d);    // call Overload 1
    int arr[5];
    friend_func(&arr);  // call Overload 2 - error in MSVC!
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the only difference between these two functions is that the second one takes a pointer to `value` `int`s instead of `dummy<value>`.
This code compiles just fine in GCC ($ gcc-4.7.2 test.cpp) and Clang (thanks [WhozCraig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322972/whozcraig)), but throws the following error in MSVC (I tested 2012):

```
1>d:\path\to.cpp(32): error C2248: 'my_class::m_member' : cannot access private member declared in class 'my_class'
1>          d:\path\to.cpp(8) : see declaration of 'my_class::m_member'
1>          d:\path\to.cpp(7) : see declaration of 'my_class'
1>          d:\path\to.cpp(40) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void friend_func<5>(int (*)[5])' being compiled
```

To me this looks like a bug. However, is there anyone who encountered such a behavior before? Is it really a bug, or maybe there's a particular reason for the error? Any quick workaround for this?

---

**Edit:** I've been able to find a proper workaround, see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149607/msvc-friend-function-declaration-bug#15151021).

Comment: It probably doesn't help that clang eats this right up with no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a bug: [A template function parametrized on the size of an array cannot be declared as a friend of a class](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/717749/a-template-function-parametrized-on-the-size-of-an-array-cannot-be-declared-as-a-friend-of-a-class). It occurs when `value` is deduced as the size of the array for your friend template function. Here is a shortened version of your code that compiles fine. This example is the exact same code as your example except I specified the size of the array.

```
class my_class
{
    int m_member;

    template<size_t value>
    friend void friend_func(int(*)[5]);
};

template<size_t value>
void friend_func(int(*)[5])
{
    my_class instance;
    instance.m_member = value;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    friend_func<5>(&arr);
}
```

One workaround it to pass the `value` as a second function argument:

```
template <typename T>
void friend_func(T, int value)
{
    my_class instance;
    instance.m_member = value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! Your solution works. However, using it I lose the strongly-sized array overload without explicitly specifying the (possibly incorrect) size. Even more important, the first piece of code you've posted produces ambiguity when there's an overload taking `int*`. I've managed to get a better workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15151021/823663).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's a known issue with MSVS.  Your specific issue is listed in the [Portability Hints: Micrsoft Visual C++ on boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/more/microsoft_vcpp.html).

Look for Templates as Friends.  I do not know the work around.  However, I think you can make a class a friend.  You may be able to use that as a work around.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not the case. The article you've mentioned is for MSVC 6; I'm using MSVC 11. The "Templates as Friends" bug is fixed long ago, the first overload function in my opening post would issue an error if it was not.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured a workaround that preserves the functionality yet does its job of preventing the error message. The idea is to use a proxy function and a proxy class to carry the pointer to the array and it's size. Here's the solution:

```
#include <cstddef>

// Workaround class for a bug in MSVC.
// https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/717749
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149607
template<class element_type, size_t count>
class friend_declaration_bug_workaround
{
public:
    typedef element_type(*ptr_type)[count];

private:
    ptr_type m_arr;

public:
    explicit friend_declaration_bug_workaround(ptr_type arr)
        : m_arr(arr)
    {
    }

    ptr_type value() const
    {
        return m_arr;
    }
};

class my_class
{
    int m_member;

    friend void friend_func(int*);

    template<size_t value>
    friend void friend_func_workaround(friend_declaration_bug_workaround<int, value>);
};

template<size_t value>
void friend_func_workaround(friend_declaration_bug_workaround<int, value> workaround)
{
    my_class instance;
    instance.m_member = (*workaround.value())[0];
}

void friend_func(int* arr)
{
    my_class instance;
    instance.m_member = *arr;
}

template<size_t value>
void friend_func(int(*arr)[value])
{
    friend_declaration_bug_workaround<int, value> workaround(arr);
    return friend_func_workaround(workaround);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int value;
    friend_func(&value);    // call non-templated function
    int arr[5];
    friend_func(&arr);      // call workarounded function
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you could avoid all that work with `std::vector` or `std::array` ([for example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/babIB$1) or [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/babIB$5)).

Comment: @JesseGood Sure, but in my case the generic collection type (the one suitable to range-based for from C++11) was already handled by a different overload, and I needed plain C arrays.

Comment: I see, however C++11 range-based for can handle plain C arrays BTW.